# Determinant of a matrix is equal to the determinant of its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, transpose, laplace-expansion

For a square matrix A, I want to show that $$ | \mathbf{A}^T| = |\mathbf{A}| $$

Proof:

Let the same permutation that changes $ \varphi(j_1,...,j_n) $ into $ \varphi(1,...,n) $, change $ \varphi(1,...,n) $ into $ \varphi(i_1,...,i_n) $. Then, noticing that $ \varphi(1,...,n) $ = $ 0 $, we obtain

$$ |\mathbf{A}| = \sum_{(j_1,...,j_n)} (-1)^{\varphi(j_1,...,j_n)}a_{1j_1}a_{2j_2}...a_{nj_n} \quad ...(1) \quad \text{by  def. laplace expansion} $$
$$  = \sum_{(j_1,...,j_n)} (-1)^{\varphi(1,...,n)}(-1)^{\varphi(j_1,...,j_n)}a_{1j_1}a_{2j_2}...a_{nj_n} \quad ...(2)\quad \text{by  obs.} $$

Now comes the problem. My book then proceeds to this equality which I need to unpack.

$$ = \sum_{(1,...,n)} (-1)^{\varphi(i_1,...,i_n)}(-1)^{\varphi(1,...,n)}a_{i_11}a_{i_2 2}...a_{i_n n} $$

In essence, I don't quite get why one is allowed to change the indices in the summation and multiplication. From the first statement, I gather that this is a constructive proof. Nevertheless, I don't follow how the $\varphi$ can be interchanged. Intuitively, I imagine that they represent the same amount of transpositions (even or odd).

Comment: I think that you've not quite set this up correctly. What's $\phi(\dots)$? How do permutations change it?

Comment: A quick go on the Googlizer  gives a 3 x 3 general example :
https://mathinstructor.net/2012/04/determinant-of-matrix-is-equal-to-determinant-of-its-transpose-2/
and the more general result:
 http://math.clarku.edu/~ma130/determinants3.pdf

Comment: @ancientmathematician what I understand about $ \varphi(j_1, … j_n) $ is that it’s a function that takes the value of zero when the amount of transpositions needed to permutate $ (1,…,n) $ into $ (j_1,…,j_n) $ is even and one when odd.

Comment: @MartinHansen I do understand and have seen the proof that uses elementary matrices. Nevertheless, I wish to understand this other notation as to do everything by first principles. Most of the chapter in the book continues using this definition throughout.

Comment: Then when you talk about the permutations what you mean is  "the permutation that changes  $(j_1,\dots, j_n)$ to $(1,\dots, n)$ is the same as the permutation that changes $(1,\dots,n)$ to $(i_1,\dots, i_n)$"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that keeping track of these $i_r$'s and and $j_s$'s is very confusing, so I will write what I think is the same proof in a different notation.  I use $\pi$ as a general permutation of the set $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$. In your question, this is the permutation taking each $r$ to $i_r$, or equivalently taking each $j_s$ to $s$.

I would use $\mathop{sgn}(\pi)$ to denote the sign of the permutation $\pi$. (This is your $\phi$ but I don't believe that your book is using it consistently).

Then
$$
\det A=\sum_{\pi} (-1)^{\mathop{sgn}(\pi)} a_{1,\pi(1)}\dots a_{n,\pi(n)}
$$
is the Laplace expansion.

We can rewrite this by shuffling the terms as
$$
\sum_{\pi} (-1)^{\mathop{sgn}(\pi)} a_{\pi^{-1}(1),1}\dots a_{\pi^{-1}(n),n}.
$$

Now it is easy to see that $\pi$ is odd if and only if $\pi^{-1}$ is odd, so we have in fact
$$
\sum_{\pi} (-1)^{\mathop{sgn}(\pi^{-1})} a_{\pi^{-1}(1),1}\dots a_{\pi^{-1}(n),n}.
$$

Now as $\pi$ runs through the set of all permutations so does $\pi^{-1}$, so what we really have is

$$
\sum_{\pi^{-1}} (-1)^{\mathop{sgn}(\pi^{-1})} a_{\pi^{-1}(1),1}\dots a_{\pi^{-1}(n),n}.
$$

Writing $\rho$ for $\pi^{-1}$ this is

$$
\sum_{\rho} (-1)^{\mathop{sgn}(\rho)} a_{\rho(1),1}\dots a_{\rho(n),n}
$$
which is the Laplace expansion of $\det A^{T}$ and we are done.